# Unable to launch mongos

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I am attempting a simple sharding set up (on a single host without any replica set). However I am unable to go any further because this is what happens when i try to start mongos:

```
C:\>mongos --configdb localhost:27010 --port 27011
```

I get:

```
BadValue: configdb supports only replica set connection string  
try 'mongos --help' for more information
```

I am failing to see what is lacking. I tried `mongos --help`, but according to that valid arguments for --configdb are `<config replset name>/<host1:port>, <host2:port>, etc`. But this is what I've done.

I have not done anything else than starting the config server:

```
mongod --configsvr --port 27010
```

which is the one I am trying to connect the mongos to.

Any ideas on how this can be resolved?

Thankful for any advice in advance.

Comment: hi, did you able to solve this issue. I got same issue, but created a replica set of config server. but now it says No Primary detected for set.

Comment: @Er.MohitAgrawal Yes, the answer below solved my issue. Did you try lauching it with that command?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have set up the config server as a standalone mongod process, but as of MongoDB 3.4 that isn't supported: it *must* be a replicaset:

> [config servers: Config servers store metadata and configuration settings for the cluster. As of MongoDB 3.4, config servers must be deployed as a replica set (CSRS).](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/sharding/)

The minimum setup is to have a single mongod process, configured as a [1-member replica set](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/sharded-cluster-components/#development-configuration); then your mongos process connects to the replica set:

```
mongos --configdb replsetname/localhost:27010 --port 27011
```

Comment: 1-member replica sets are allowed? Thought the minimum size was 3.

Comment: No, minimum size is 1 - remember, as soon as you initiate a replica set on a single mongod process it is fully functioning as a replica set. But: obviously in anything but a toy system, you would want multiple members in your replica set to get the benefits.

Comment: See https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/sharded-cluster-components/#development-configuration